# How to find $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x+x^2+\sqrt{x}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How to find

$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x+x^2+\sqrt{x}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}?
$$

---

My try : $$(\sqrt[3]{x}-1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)=(x-1)$$

So we have :

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x+x^2+\sqrt{x}-3}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1} \cdot\frac{(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}{(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x+x^2+\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}{x-1}$$

Now what ?

Comment: Set $t = \sqrt{x}$. Then find a common factor in denominator and numerator.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $$t=\sqrt[6]{x}$$ then we have $$t^6=x$$ and we get
$$\frac{t^{12}+t^6+t^3-3}{t^2-1}$$

Comment: The denominator should be $t^2-1$.

Comment: indeed, just corrected

Comment: No problem. Adding the following expression might be helpful:$$t^{12}+t^6+t^3-3 = (t-1)(t^{11}+t^{10}+ \cdots t^{6}+ 2(t^5+t^4+t^3)+3(t^2+t+1)).$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

> $$x+x^{ 2 }+\sqrt { x } -3=x-1+x^{ 2 }-1+\sqrt { x } -1=x-1+\left( x-1 \right) \left( x+1 \right) +\sqrt { x } -1=\left( x-1 \right) \left( 1+x-1 \right) +\sqrt { x } -1=x\left( x-1 \right) +\sqrt { x } -1=\\ =x\left( \sqrt { x } -1 \right) \left( \sqrt { x } +1 \right) +\sqrt { x } -1=\left( \sqrt { x } -1 \right) \left( x\sqrt { x } +x+1 \right) $$